# How to change canvas position in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've started in Unity with Roll-a-Ball tutorial. And now I have a trouble with UI Lesson: when I create Text element Canvas parent creates in strange position:

[image: screenshot]

But in lesson I see that Canvas is near Player object. How can I move it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the bit in your canvas inspector about it being "screen space - overlay"?

That means:

"**This render mode places UI elements on the screen rendered on top of the scene.** "

And what THAT means, is that you don't have to worry about where the Canvas and child Text show up in your scene view.  When you run the game the UI elements will overlay on the background world objects and it'll all be fine.

Source:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UICanvas.html

Answer (score 11):

If you want to see the canvas fit inside your scene camera's view, change the Canvas's Render Mode to Screen Space - Camera; then drag the Main Camera onto the newly visible Render Camera field in the inspector.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't matter where the canvas is located, but you can select the child object called 'text' and change the X and Y values to move it around the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In canvas Change that Screen SpaceOvarlay to WorldSpace

Comment: Please describe the effect of what you propose and explain why that helps to solve the problem.